# Why CSP is not working in .net core and Angular App?

Tags: asp.net-core, content-security-policy, x-frame-options

I have a .net core and Angular 2 SaaS app. I'm trying to implement X-Frame-Options: Deny and Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none'; to prevent my app to be embedded into other frames.

I have implemented it in different ways in my .net Core API and getting them in the response header values. The expected behavior is the iframe's content (which is my web app) is blocked, but still it is loading the app.

.Net Core Implementation:

**First Approach:**

```
    app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
    {
        ctx.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options",
                 "deny");
        ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy",
                                 "frame-ancestors 'none'; report-uri /cspreport");
        await next();
    });
```

**The second Approach using Nwebsec**

```
   app.UseXfo(o => o.Deny());
   app.UseCsp(options => options.FrameAncestors(s => s.None()));
```

I also added below meta tag in the head section of the index.html file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" charset="utf-8">
```

Below is my network tab showing the header values into the response header:

[image]

I read lots of guides and documents, but still, I can see my app is loading into the iframe.

Any help/tip will be much appreciated.

**Update**
Both .net core API and Angular app are deployed in two different Azure App Services.

Answer (score 0):

CSP frame-ancestors and X-Frame-Options is used to prevent framing of documents (typically with content-type text/html). Your response is returning application/json, but you are likely not embedding the response as such. Framing prevention will not help in this case.

Data (such as application/json) is typically restricted through CORS headers, and you should probably be more restrictive with your Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.